Correctly construct a monorepo library including typescript
I've written a library for connecting to a third-party API and providing convenience wrappers around it's functions:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@opoint/opoint
https://github.com/queenvictoria/opoint
I am having difficulting figuring out how to correctly set up the workspace, namespace, and build pipeline so that one can easily import it into a typescript project or a vanilla js project:
import { StoredSearch } from '@opoint/storedsearch'
import {
  DocumentProps as OpointDocumentProps,
  StoredSearchFeedProps,
  StoredSearchFeedResponse
} from '@opoint/types'

The way it is written now I get errors in my implementation that imports the libraries such as:
 FAIL  tests/opoint-storedsearch.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@opoint/storedsearch' from 'src/opoint-storedsearch.ts'

    Require stack:
      src/opoint-storedsearch.ts
      tests/opoint-storedsearch.test.ts

      1 | import { BaseReceiver } from './base'
    > 2 | import { StoredSearch } from '@opoint/storedsearch'
        | ^
      3 | import {
      4 |   DocumentProps as OpointDocumentProps,
      5 |   StoredSearchFeedProps,

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/opoint-storedsearch.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/opoint-storedsearch.test.ts:5:1)

I'm not using Learna or any of the other tooling around maintaining monorepos--just trying to use npm workspaces directly.
I've created a vanilla js example here and a typescript example here for reference.
Can anyone see what I've done incorrectly (in the @opoint library) or point me in the right direction please?
[UPDATE] I seem to have resolved this in a sweeping refactor. If anyone can pinpoint which specific changes fixed the issue and would like to write it up and explain it I'll accept their answer.
PR here:
https://github.com/queenvictoria/opoint/pull/2

Please add your package.json and tsconfig files, the root, and the project

Hi @mseyfayi all those files are in the opoint repo linked above are they not? What do I need to add them to?

@mseyfayi I've created two sample implementations and added them to my original question. My intention in those was to make them as vanilla as possible. If you can see any weird setup in the typescript config in the opoint-test-ts repo please let me know.
